# Mix SSL with client certificate and without client certificate in one application pool

Tags: wcf, iis, ssl, ssl-certificate

Is it possible in WCF to have an endpoint with SSL and a client certificate and an endpoint with another contract with SSL and without a client certificate within the same application pool in IIS?
If this is possible, this should somehow be configured add the service or endpoint level?

**UPDATE**

If I set the IIS SSL settings to require a client certificate, my service without client certificate doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As the binding is part of the endpoint I see no indicator why it would not be possible to configure the service with 2 different endpoints just as you said. The application pool has nothing to do with bindings.

If you encountered specific problems while trying to do so, it would be helpful to post them.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question? 
I don't have problems configuring 2 enpoints.
I have a problem configuring 2 endpoints on the same application pool: one with SSL and client certificate and one with SSL and without client certificate.
If I set the SSL client certificate setting in IIS to "Require", my other endpoint without client certificate doesn't work anymore

Comment: I may have been confused by your mention of application pool, because the application pool has nothing to do with it. You might want to edit your question so people understand you want to have two bindings *on the same service* one requiring the client cert, one not. Have you tried to not set it in IIS, but set it differently in the service bindings themselves?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, using the location tag in my web.config, so the service with client certificate was placed in a different directory and configured like this:

```
  <location path="WithoutClientCertificate">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <access sslFlags="Ssl" />
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="WithClientCertificate">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
```